# Not able to get admin logged in session

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm writing a custom import script that needs to allow admins only to work. I'm new to Magento and having trouble extracting the session. It's actually an old script someone else wrote, and I'm trying to make sense of it. What I did so far was create a directory `product_import` in the root folder and put the following in `index.php`:

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/../app/Mage.php');
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);


if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn() === false) {
    echo 'Not logged in!'; die();
}

echo 'Logged in!';
```

Now, even though I'm logged in as admin, I keep getting the `Not logged in` message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. For some reason, it doesn't work if the file is inside another directory. I moved it to project root and it worked. The only thing I don't know is . . . why? :-)